# why heroku application error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cloud9

I pushed all my code to heroku and when I give it the command heroku domains to access my work. The heroku page gives me application error.
and these are the logs.

```
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182579+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182580+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182581+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182582+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182583+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182584+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182585+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182587+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182588+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182589+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182590+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182604+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:288:in `initialize!'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182604+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182605+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `require'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182607+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182607+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182608+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182609+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182610+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182611+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182613+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182614+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182626+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182627+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182628+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in `app'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182628+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182629+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:250:in `start'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182630+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182630+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182632+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182632+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182633+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182634+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182636+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `require'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.182637+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2017-07-16T03:37:15.277934+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-07-16T03:37:15.264831+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-07-16T08:56:50.023136+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=francophone-inukshuk-10644.herokuapp.com request_id=27b2d524-48dd-4c93-8d7c-afa14f7ccaa7 fwd="41.239.63.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2017-07-16T08:56:50.910825+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=francophone-inukshuk-10644.herokuapp.com request_id=ce505a0d-de1e-4f4c-b825-ce891ef2685c fwd="41.239.63.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2017-07-16T08:56:51.663725+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=francophone-inukshuk-10644.herokuapp.com request_id=6083341c-6096-428f-8c70-80108f3fad89 fwd="41.239.63.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2017-07-16T08:58:35.306777+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=francophone-inukshuk-10644.herokuapp.com request_id=48674ea3-fde0-4e6a-b09d-4f04845dc28a fwd="41.239.63.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2017-07-16T08:58:35.910619+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=francophone-inukshuk-10644.herokuapp.com request_id=eaf9d3c3-f75f-4d1a-b1e0-e7f730777d84 fwd="41.239.63.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2017-07-16T09:17:40.559334+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=francophone-inukshuk-10644.herokuapp.com request_id=dcefa7f5-96a9-4461-823e-b40ca8910dab fwd="41.239.63.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2017-07-16T09:17:41.266886+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=francophone-inukshuk-10644.herokuapp.com request_id=36260ad7-8e57-4604-999c-1b12e1a69ed6 fwd="41.239.63.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2017-07-16T09:21:31.687856+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-07-16T09:21:34.507130+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 37743 -e production`
2017-07-16T09:21:37.693633+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:285: warning: circular argument reference - now
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880081+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880097+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.1.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:37743
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880098+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880100+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880105+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880100+00:00 app[web.1]: => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880142+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/mailers/contact_mailer.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ActiveMailer (NameError)
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880144+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:468:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880145+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `each'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880147+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `block in eager_load!'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880149+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `eager_load!'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880150+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880148+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `each'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880209+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `each'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880210+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880210+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880211+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880212+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880212+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880213+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880214+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880214+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880215+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880216+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880215+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880216+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880217+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880217+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880218+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:288:in `initialize!'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880218+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880219+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `require'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880219+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880220+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880220+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880220+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880221+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880221+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880222+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880222+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880223+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880223+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880223+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in `app'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880224+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880226+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:250:in `start'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880226+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880227+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880227+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880227+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880228+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880228+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880229+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `require'
2017-07-16T09:21:38.880229+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2017-07-16T09:21:39.037285+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-07-16T09:21:39.025315+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Comment: Show us your `contact_mailer.rb`code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
uninitialized constant ActiveMailer (NameError)
```

This means that Ruby was trying to find the class or module `ActiveMailer` but was unable to do so. The email sending library of Rails is called **ActionMailer**, not ActiveMailer.

Try changing `ActiveMailer` to `ActionMailer` in your `contact_mailer.rb` file.

Comment: I modified it to `ActionMailer` but still does not work. When I run the command `heroku domains` it outputs `▸    heroku-cli: This CLI is deprecated. Please reinstall from https://cli.heroku.com
=== arcane-eyrie-96228 Heroku Domain
arcane-eyrie-96228.herokuapp.com` and when I open the givin link, it still gives me the same error which is "Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details." @Máté Solymosi